# How can I use LSTM with pretrained static word vectors on aclImdb dataset

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I am trying to use Sentiment Classification with LSTM and pre-trained BERT embeddings, and later language translation with Transformer
first of all I downloaded

```
!pip install ktrain
!pip install tensorflow_text
```

And I imported the necessary lib

```
import pathlib
import random
import numpy as np
from typing import Tuple, List

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# tensoflow imports
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    TextVectorization, LSTM, Dense, Embedding, Dropout,
    Layer, Input, MultiHeadAttention, LayerNormalization)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow_text as tf_text 
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
```

And I downloaded and extracted Large Movie dataset from Stanford

```
!wget https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
!tar -xzf aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
```

1- I try to use LSTM with train by Creating the training and test sets with the texts_from_folder function of the ktrain.text module

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID";
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0";

DATADIR ='/content/aclImdb'
trn, val, preproc = text.texts_from_folder(DATADIR,max_features=20000, maxlen=400, ngram_range=1,                                               preprocess_mode='standard', train_test_names=['train', 'test'],classes=['pos', 'neg'])
```

And I am trying to build LSTM model her

```
K.clear_session()    
def build_LSTM_model(
        embedding_size: int,
        total_words: int,
        lstm_hidden_size: int,
        dropout_rate: float) -> Sequential:
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = total_words,output_dim=embedding_size,input_length=total_words))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_hidden_size,return_sequences=True,name="lstm_layer"))
    model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
#     model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN, activation="relu"))
#     adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='CategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['CategoricalAccuracy'])
    model.summary()
    model = Sequential()
```

with the following requirements  for a sequential model The model should include:
One Embedding layer at the beginning. (Watch out for proper parameterization!)
At least one LSTM layer.At least one Dropout layer for regularization.One final Dense layer mapping to the outputs.
compile model, with categorical_crossentropy loss and the adam optimizer. or might want to add other types of metrics for example CategoricalAccuracy makes sense here.

And then I want to use the **ktrain library**'s **get_learner** method to create an easily trainable version of the previous model. and to use test set as the **val_data**, to see the performance. ( not include the proper train-validation-test split, but it could be extended if required.)
I am using the  **learner's** **lr_find** and **lr_plot** methods to determine the most effective learning rate for the model. by Specifying the **max_epochs** parameter of **lr_find** to limit the time this takes.  a couple of epochs! to determine the best learning rate based on the plot. and find balance between the fastest convergence and stability

```
learner: ktrain.Learner
model = text.text_classifier('bert', trn , preproc=preproc)
learner.lr_find()
learner.lr_plot()
learner.fit_onecycle(1e-4, 1)
```

I faced following errors
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
6 #                              workers=8, use_multiprocessing=False, batch_size=64)
7
----> 8 model = text.text_classifier('bert', trn , preproc=preproc)

```
     10 # learner.lr_find()
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ktrain/text/models.py in _text_model(name, train_data, preproc, multilabel, classification, metrics, verbose)
    109         raise ValueError(
    110             "if '%s' is selected model, then preprocess_mode='%s' should be used and vice versa"
--> 111             % (BERT, BERT)
    112         )    113     is_huggingface = U.is_huggingface(data=train_data)
ValueError: if 'bert' is selected model, then preprocess_mode='bert' should be used and vice versa
```

And next step to make it with **LSTM with pretrained** static word vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using BERT for pretrained word vectors supplied as features to an LSTM, then you don't need to build a separate BERT classification model. You can use `TransformerEmbedding` to generate word vectors for your dataset (or use [sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net/)):

```py
In [1]: from ktrain.text import TransformerEmbedding

In [2]: te = TransformerEmbedding('bert-base-cased')

In [3]: te.embed('George Washington went to Washington .').shape
Out[3]: (1, 6, 768)
```

This is what the [included NER models](https://nbviewer.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/CoNLL2003-BiLSTM.ipynb) in **ktrain** do under-the-hood.

Also, the input feature format for a BERT model is completely different than input features for an LSTM.  As the error message indicates, to preprocess your texts for BERT classification model, you'll need to supply `preprocess_mode='bert'` to `texts_from_folder`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer the question I need to re-implement LSTM function  model as described at beginning